# Agregar polyline en onMarkerClickListener()

Tags: android, google-maps

Tengo un programa donde necesito agregar un `polyline`  al clickear un marcador y si clickeo un marcador diferente se borre la anterior y agregue la nueva.

Hasta el momento agrega la linea y borra la anterior y agrega la nueva, el problema es que los puntos del `polyline` se sobrescriban agregándose mas de una vez por lo que se deforma la `polyline`

**Código**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    ArrayList<FormatoPolyline> Poly=new ArrayList<>();
    Polyline line;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        int height = 50;
        int width = 50;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
        Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
        marcadores(mMap,smallMarker);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-33.502482,-70.573841), 15f));


        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                Polylines(mMap,marker.getTitle());
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
 public void Polylines(GoogleMap map, String ruta){
 ArrayList<LatLng>puntos=new ArrayList<>();
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions= new PolylineOptions();

        if(line!=null) {
            line.remove();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<Poly.size();i++){
            if (Poly.get(i).getTitulo().equals(ruta)){
                LatLng punto=Poly.get(i).getPunto();
                puntos.add(punto);
                Log.d("punto",""+String.valueOf(Poly.get(i).getPunto()));
            }
        }
        Log.d("tamaño",String.valueOf(puntos.size()));
        polylineOptions.addAll(puntos).width(8).color(Color.RED);
        line = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

            puntos.clear();

    }
    public void marcadores(GoogleMap map, Bitmap smallMarker){
 map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.459932,-70.574753)).title("Dublé Almeyda").snippet("Vereda / Poniente a Oriente / Los Corteses a Exequiel Figueroa ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.4442263,-70.560658)).title("Echeñique").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Tobalaba a Vicente Pérez Rosales ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.401914,-70.629014)).title("Einstein / Las Torres").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Antonia Prado a Los Zapadores ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.6410041,-70.7339984)).title("El Barrancón").snippet("Vereda / Norte a Sur / Camino Calera De Tango a Santa Inés ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.589223,-70.800941)).title("El Copihue").snippet("Vereda / Bidireccional / Los Nogales a Camino a Lonquén ").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-33.502482,-70.573841)).title("Los Cerezos").snippet("Los Cerezos").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    }
}
```

si ejecuto una vez el método la linea queda asi:

```
 06-15 21:56:33.966 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.505714000000005,-70.574659)
    06-15 21:56:33.966 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.505027,-70.574479)
    06-15 21:56:33.966 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.503835,-70.574168)
    06-15 21:56:33.966 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.502827,-70.573889)
    06-15 21:56:33.966 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.502482,-70.573841)
    06-15 21:56:33.966 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50191,-70.573704)
    06-15 21:56:33.966 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50087,-70.573441)
    06-15 21:56:33.966 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50004,-70.573224)
    06-15 21:56:33.966 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/tamaño: 8
```

pero si presiono el mismo marcador una vez mas:

```
 06-15 21:57:48.938 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.505714000000005,-70.574659)
    06-15 21:57:48.938 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.505027,-70.574479)
    06-15 21:57:48.938 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.503835,-70.574168)
    06-15 21:57:48.938 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.502827,-70.573889)
    06-15 21:57:48.938 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.502482,-70.573841)
    06-15 21:57:48.939 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50191,-70.573704)
    06-15 21:57:48.939 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50087,-70.573441)
    06-15 21:57:48.939 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50004,-70.573224)
    06-15 21:57:48.943 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.505714000000005,-70.574659)
    06-15 21:57:48.943 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.505027,-70.574479)
    06-15 21:57:48.943 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.503835,-70.574168)
    06-15 21:57:48.943 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.502827,-70.573889)
    06-15 21:57:48.943 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.502482,-70.573841)
    06-15 21:57:48.943 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50191,-70.573704)
    06-15 21:57:48.943 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50087,-70.573441)
    06-15 21:57:48.943 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50004,-70.573224)
    06-15 21:57:48.944 14152-14152/com.example.nacho.mapa D/tamaño: 16
```

mantiene los puntos de la primera ejecución y los vuelve agregar, por lo que se deforma la `polyline`

**Update**

Creo haber encontrado el error:

```
 if(line!=null) {
                line.remove();
                line=null;
                Log.d("Polyline","no es nula");
            }

            for(int i=0;i<Poly.size();i++){
                if (Poly.get(i).getTitulo().equals(ruta)){
                    LatLng punto=Poly.get(i).getPunto();
                    puntos.add(punto);
                    Log.d("punto",""+String.valueOf(Poly.get(i).getPunto()));
                }
            }

            polylineOptions= new PolylineOptions();
            Log.d("tamaño",String.valueOf(puntos.size()));
            polylineOptions.addAll(puntos).width(8).color(Color.RED);
            line = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
            puntos.clear();
    // reviso directamente los puntos del polyline y si existen los intento remover
            if(line.getPoints().isEmpty()){
                Log.d("puntos","vacio");
            }else{
                line.getPoints().clear();
                line.getPoints().removeAll(line.getPoints());
                Log.d("puntos","contiene puntos");
            }
```

ejecute el codigo y el logcat me muestra lo siguiente:

```
 06-16 22:17:55.690 31525-31525/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.505714000000005,-70.574659)
    06-16 22:17:55.691 31525-31525/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.505027,-70.574479)
    06-16 22:17:55.691 31525-31525/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.503835,-70.574168)
    06-16 22:17:55.691 31525-31525/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.502827,-70.573889)
    06-16 22:17:55.691 31525-31525/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.502482,-70.573841)
    06-16 22:17:55.691 31525-31525/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50191,-70.573704)
    06-16 22:17:55.692 31525-31525/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50087,-70.573441)
    06-16 22:17:55.692 31525-31525/com.example.nacho.mapa D/punto: lat/lng: (-33.50004,-70.573224)
    06-16 22:17:55.692 31525-31525/com.example.nacho.mapa D/tamaño: 8
    06-16 22:17:55.706 31525-31525/com.example.nacho.mapa D/puntos: contiene puntos
```

por ende el problema no es del arreglo sino que la PolylineOptions no se limpia en cada ejecución, necesito ver encontrar la forma que polylineoptions se vuelva nula al comienzo de la ejecucion del metodo, probe con:

> polylineOptions=null;

pero no funciono.

Comment: Revisa lo que comento en mi respuesta. @zhet

Comment: y si haces polylineOptions= new PolylineOptions(); en vez de polylineOptions = null???

Comment: Lo intente, pero no se sobreescribe el valor

Comment: Prueba a crear un ArrayList auxiliar donde introduzcas los puntos nuevos al clickar sobre un marcador y luego el Array original lo igualas a este auxiliar, así debería sobreescribir el array, debería...

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano tampoco me funciono

Comment: repare el problema cambiando el formato del arreglo poly a este (titulo,PolylineOptions), despues la cargue tal y como lo hacia y ya no se sobreescribe

Answer (score 1):

He visto lo que preguntabas pero cerraste la pregunta, en este caso te sugiero definir el `ArrayList` `puntos` a nivel de clase:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    ArrayList<FormatoPolyline> Poly=new ArrayList<>();
    Polyline line;

   ArrayList<LatLng> puntos = new ArrayList<>(); //***
...
...
```

y comentar la que generas dentro de Polylines() :

```
public void Polylines(GoogleMap map, String ruta){
  //ArrayList<LatLng>puntos=new ArrayList<>();
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions= new PolylineOptions();

        if(line!=null) {
            line.remove();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<Poly.size();i++){
            if (Poly.get(i).getTitulo().equals(ruta)){
                LatLng punto=Poly.get(i).getPunto();
                puntos.add(punto);
                Log.d("punto",""+String.valueOf(Poly.get(i).getPunto()));
            }
        }
        Log.d("tamaño",String.valueOf(puntos.size()));
        polylineOptions.addAll(puntos).width(8).color(Color.RED);
        line = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

            puntos.clear();

    }
```

Comment: documente todo el método, espero haya sido lo suficientemente claro para que entiendas lo que quise hacer

Comment: añadi una actualizacion mas a la pregunta

Comment: te di los 50 para que no se perdieran, encontre la respuesta igual